# create Inline Boxes

Tags: horizontal-alignment, boxes, tcolorbox

I would like to create two boxes next to each other horizontally, each containing text. I'd like the border to be black and the background white.

[image]

Here's my attempt at reproducing it

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
{\tcbox{Modals}=\tcbox{Helping verbs} }
\end{center}
\[\fbox{\mbox{Modals}}=\fbox{\mbox{Helping verbs}}\]

\end{document}
```

which produces

[image]

Comment: Don't use `$$`, see [Why is `\[ … \]` preferable to `$$`?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503)

Comment: @samcarter thank you for reminding me with that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are better to define your own command:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\newtcbox{\mybox}{
  colback=white,% background color
  on line,% don't add line breaks
  before upper=\vphantom{Ay},% ensure constant height
}

\begin{document}
\[
\mybox{Modals}=\mybox{Helping verbs}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]